# Problems referencing canvas position

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, canvas

Unfortunately jsfiddle seems to be down today, so I'll try my best to describe what I am after.

I do have two divs that are of fixed size (100px by 100px). These are jquery-UI-draggable.

Markup looking like this:

```
<body>
<div class="touch" id="front"><img src="front.png" /></div>
<div class="touch" id="back"><img src="back.png" /></div>
<canvas id="connect"></canvas>
</body>
```

and the CSS looking like this:

```
.touch{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
#connect{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Now I am trying to use canvas to draw a line that connects these two divs by doing the following on `drag`:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();  
ctx.moveTo($('#front').offset().left,$('#front').offset().top);  
ctx.lineTo($('#back').offset().left,$('#back').offset().top);  
ctx.stroke();
```

This is working as a line is drawn according to the movements of the `div`s, yet it is completely out of proportions, i.e. the starting and end points seem to be multiplied by some factor. Yet, when I draw an element by hardcoded values it seems to work fine and when I log the `offset()`-values they seem plausible. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting your Canvas width and height by CSS and not by the width and height attributes. Canvas is special in this way.

The canvas is 300x150 by default and still is, its just "stretched" by CSS to be 100%/100%.

I strongly recommend against ever defining the size of a canvas in CSS since you will only ever be scaling it away from its "true" size.

In code during setup you are going to have to do

```
// silly pseudocode
canvas.width = theCanvasParent.clientWidth; // or whatever attribute it is, I'd reccomend putting all of those things in one giant container div
canvas.height = theCanvasParent.clientHeight;
```

Since most browsers do not fire an event when the parent div changes size, you'll simply have to check, say, every half second with a timer to see if the div has changed size. If it has, then you resize the canvas accordingly.

Comment: I ended up using something as simple as `canvas.width = document.width; canvas.height = document.height;` which works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: just a quick note, that will work until the user resizes the window, but will be broken if the user has something like the StumbleUpon bar installed, because that bar adds a margin to the `<html>` element. It's pretty rare though.

Comment: Interesting hint, but as this will be used in a Phonegap based Android App with locked orientation the number of possible pitfalls is greatly reduced in this case. Lucky me. Thanks.